# Alterar ConnectionString apenas em memória runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework

No App.config de minha aplicação criptografei a ConnectionString, agora preciso decriptografar em runtime mas não atualizando no arquivo App.config.

Estou utilizando o seguinte código, mas o mesmo acaba alterando no arquivo perdendo a lógica de eu deixar criptografado.

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var connectionString = (ConnectionStringsSection) config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
connectionString.ConnectionStrings["ControleBD"].ConnectionString = "Data Source=NewSource;Initial Catalog=NewCatalog;UID=NewUser;password=NewPassword";
config.Save();
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

Comment: Descriptografar a senha perde o sentido de ter criptografado. Seu problema é outro.

Comment: O usual é criptografar apenas usuário e senha, descriptografar e usar em runtime. Você está criptografando toda a connection string, o que pode dificultar reconfiguração do ambiente (mudança de servidor, por exemplo). E por que você está atualizando a string de conexão no arquivo de configuração em runtime?

Comment: Dá uma estudada neste artigo: [Security Considerations (Entity Framework)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716760(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: @Caffé obrigado pelo link, otimo artigo.

Comment: a parte da criptografia não coloquei neste trecho de código, a função estaria na atribuição da terceira linha. Minha necessidade seria apenas esconder este tipo de informação de um usuário simples.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, você não está criptografando a senha, sequer está protegendo a mesma. afinal você pode "decompilar" a sua dll usando ferramentas como [`decompiler`](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)

Se você deseja proteger os seus dados sensiveis, você deve mover o conteudo da seção `appSettings` e `connectionStrings` para um arquivo separado usando o atributo `file` e `configSource` respectivamente.

O exemplo abaixo foi retirado do seguinte link: [`Best practices for deploying passwords and other sensitive data to ASP.NET and Azure App Service`](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/best-practices-for-deploying-passwords-and-other-sensitive-data-to-aspnet-and-azure#con)

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ControleBD" connectionString="Data Source=NewSource;Initial Catalog=NewCatalog;UID=NewUser;password=NewPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings> 
  <!-- Informação Sensivel -->
  <add key="serviceAccount" value="account" />
  <add key="servicePassword" value="my password" />
  <!-- Informação Não Sensivel-->
  <add key="Versao" value="1.2.3.4" />
</appSettings>
```

neste caso, você pode criar dois arquivos, um para a string de conexão e outro para as configurações.:

**\app.config ou \web.config**

```
<connectionStrings configSource="\App_Configs\connectionStrings.config">
  <add name="ControleBD" connectionString="Data Source=NewSource;Initial Catalog=NewCatalog;UID=NewUser;password=NewPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings file="\App_Configs\appSettings.config"> 
  <add key="Versao" value="1.2.3.4" />
</appSettings>
```

**\App_Configs\connectionStrings.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ControleBD" connectionString="Data Source=NewSource;Initial Catalog=NewCatalog;UID=NewUser;password=NewPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**\App_Configs\appSettings.config**

```
<appSettings> 
  <add key="serviceAccount" value="account" />
  <add key="servicePassword" value="my password" />
</appSettings>
```

Então você deverá limitar o acesso a estes dois arquivos.

Agora se você deseja criptografar uma seção do web.config, então faça uso do `aspnet_regiis.exe`, para saber onde o mesmo está localizado, abra o `Command Prompt` do seu `Visual Studio` e digite `where aspnet_regiis`, no meu caso ele está localizado em:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe
```

então execute o `aspnet_regiis` passando os seguintes argumentos:

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" 'Path Completo para o diretorio com o web.config'
```

Para saber mais sobre o `aspnet_regiis`, acesso o link: [`Ferramenta de registro ASP.NET IIS (Aspnet_regiis.exe)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.100).aspx)

Lembrando que caso o seu arquivo de configuração tenha um nome diferente de `web.config`, você deverá renomea-lo para `web.config`. e se deseja manter a `connectionStrings` em um arquivo separado, deverá move-lo apos criptografar a seção.

Comment: Considerando todo o contexto da pergunta, acredito que o AP na verdade tenha omitido do código a descriptografia da connectionstring em vez de deixá-la hardcoded como pode parecer. Ou pelo menos quero acreditar hahaha